# MQTT: Python script should subscribe to subtopics

Tags: python, mqtt, subscribe

we're working on a project where some sensors send data to a mqtt broker and we wrote a python script which takes this data and stores it in a csv file.
now when we're adding more sensors our topics vary like this:
topic/sensor1
topic/sensor2
and so on. Now we want to get the subtopics automated in this script to not hardcode it when a sensor is added or removed.
Have you any suggestions, how we can subscribe in a loop to all subtopics?

We have the following so far:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import logging
from datetime import datetime

def on_subscribe(mosq, obj, mid, granted_qos):
    print("Subscribed: " + str(mid))

def on_log(client, userdata, level, buf):
    print(buf)

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))

    client.subscribe("envdata/#")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    f = open("log.csv", "a")
    msg_decoded = str(msg.payload, 'utf-8')
    msg_decoded = msg_decoded.replace("\n","")
    msg_decoded = msg_decoded + "\ttime:" + datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") + "\n"
    f.write(msg_decoded)
    f.close()
    print(msg.topic+" "+msg_decoded)

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.on_log = on_log
client.on_subscribe = on_subscribe

client.username_pw_set(user, password=password)
client.connect(url, 1883, 60)

client.loop_forever()
```

Comment: Tell us what you have tried and give us some code to work on.

Comment: Thanks for the advide, I edited the question and put in some code. The script works for several topics, but we want to change it so it generates one file per subtopic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We figured it out. So as we subscribe to each subtopic with `client.subscribe("topic/#")` we can access all topcs in `on_message` callback with `msg.topic`.
And now we can store this topic in a string which represents the `.csv` file.
So our `on_message` callback now looks like the following:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    filename = msg.topic
    filename = filename.replace("/","-")
    f = open(filename + ".csv", "a")
    msg_decoded = str(msg.payload, 'utf-8')
    msg_decoded = msg_decoded.replace("\n","")
    msg_decoded = msg_decoded + "\ttime:" + datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") + "\n"
    f.write(msg_decoded)
    f.close()
    print(msg.topic+" "+msg_decoded)
```

This works fine for what we wanted to reach with this script. Now when new messages are recognised by the script it opens or creates a file like `topic-subtopic.csv` and fills it with the expected data.